# Plugin Essential Blocks for Gutenberg - Fix that maintains image aspect ratios

Tags: css, plugins, block, wordpress-gutenberg

I am looking for a solution to a problem with Plugin Essential Blocks for Gutenberg.

Problem: The images have 2 ways to be viewed, in grid and in masonry. If you select grid and insert 4 images of different sizes the system crops the images to form a square I think 300x300.

If you choose masonry the images take the original size but as there are very small images and other big ones, it looks very bad.

What I am looking for: That the image has the same percentage or value of 300 but that the width is respected. I leave an image of what I want.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BopAi.png)

https://blog.logrocket.com/how-create-responsive-image-gallery-css-flexbox/

And a website where I saw the result that looks amazing and that this plugin does not bring.

You must scroll to the TITLE that says: Responsive image gallery maintaining image aspect ratios.

I'm using Elementor and Elementor Pro, but the content is inside a Post Type, and I use Gutenberg. The plugin that has this error is Essential Blocks for Gutenberg. And no word yet when they will release an update with this setting.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a good fit for Stack Overflow. Are you looking for support? Off-topic. Or a different plugin? Recommendation questions are off-topic. Or debugging help? Show us what you tried so far.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hello, I already commented but I don't know if you received the notification, I don't know the platform.